# How to populate datatable B based on selecting a column value in datatable A

Tags: primefaces

I am working on Primefaces and want to select particular column value based on selecting a column value in datatable A

```
<p:dataTable var="record" value="#{upshighlevel.upstclist1}" id="highLevelTable"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{upshighlevel.selectedOverView}" rowKey="#{record}" 
                paginator="true" rows="10" resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" 
                scrollWidth="100%" scrollHeight="150" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                            {RowsPerPageDropdown} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
                            {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})">

                 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{upshighlevel.onRowSelect}" update=":form:drillDownTable"/>
```

I am ussing rowSelect event how we make it for column select?

Answer (score 0):

There is no columSelect event as you already found out and in this case it would even be cellSelect I pressume.

And why so difficult? Why not just do

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandLink value="#{cellValue}" 
       actionListener="#{selectionBean.selectCell(cellValue)}"
       update="myOtherDatatable" />
</p:column>
```

Just clicking on the cell fires the actionListener and updates the other datatable.